# Array result into DataGridView

Tags: vb.net

I need to fill a DataGridView with the results of that function.

This function counts the lines of every file in the directory indicated, but I need to know specifically how many lines per file.

So instead of that msgbox showing the total number of lines I would like to fill the datagrid with that information.

I've been doing this without much vb.net knowledge or coding whatsoever, so any help would be greatly appreciated

```
Imports System
Imports System.Collections
Imports System.Linq
Imports System.IO
Imports System.IO.StreamReader
Imports System.IO.FileInfo
Imports System.IO.DirectoryInfo

Public Class Form1

    '/ this function returns the count of code lines
    'FileNames holds the names of files in the project directories
    Protected FileNames As New ArrayList(200)

    ' it returns filenames in the project
    Public ReadOnly Property FilesInProject() As ArrayList
        Get
            Return FileNames
        End Get
    End Property

    ' this function returns the count of code lines
    Public Function GetLineCount() As Integer

        Dim LineCount As Integer = 0

        ' this array holds file types, you can add more file types if you want
        Dim myFileArray As [String]() = New [String](6) {"*.txt", "*.doc", "*.docx", "*.odt", "*.pdf", "*.rtf", _
            "*.csv"}

        ' this array holds directories where your project files resides
        Dim myDirectoryArray As [String]() = New [String](0) {"c:\test\"}

        'this loops directories
        For Each sd As [String] In myDirectoryArray
            Dim dir As New DirectoryInfo(sd)

            ' this loops file types
            For Each sFileType As [String] In myFileArray

                ' this loops files
                For Each file__1 As FileInfo In dir.GetFiles(sFileType)

                    ' add the file name to FileNames ArrayList
                    FileNames.Add(file__1.FullName)

                    ' open files for streamreader
                    Dim sr As StreamReader = File.OpenText(file__1.FullName)

                    'loop until the end
                    While sr.ReadLine() IsNot Nothing
                        LineCount += 1
                    End While
                    'close the streamreader
                    sr.Close()

                Next
            Next
        Next
        Return LineCount

    End Function

    Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As System.Object, e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click

        Try
            MsgBox(GetLineCount)
            ' i want to put here something like datagridview1.datasource = getlinecount
        Catch ex As Exception
            MsgBox(ex.Message)
        End Try

    End Sub

    Private Sub DataGridView1_CellContentClick(sender As System.Object, e As System.Windows.Forms.DataGridViewCellEventArgs) Handles DataGridView1.CellContentClick

    End Sub

End Class
```

@htm11h here is the edited code:

```
Imports System
Imports System.Collections
Imports System.Linq
Imports System.IO
Imports System.IO.StreamReader
Imports System.IO.FileInfo
Imports System.IO.DirectoryInfo

Public Class Form1

    Dim results1 As New DataTable
    '/ this function returns the count of code lines
    'FileNames holds the names of files in the project directories
    Public FileNames As New ArrayList(200)

    ' it returns filenames in the project
    Public ReadOnly Property FilesInProject() As ArrayList
        Get
            Return FileNames
        End Get
    End Property

    ' this function returns the count of code lines
    Public Function GetLineCount() As Integer

        Dim LineCount As Integer = 0

        ' this array holds file types, you can add more file types if you want
        Dim myFileArray As [String]() = New [String](6) {"*.txt", "*.doc", "*.docx", "*.odt", "*.pdf", "*.rtf", _
            "*.csv"}

        ' this array holds directories where your project files resides
        Dim myDirectoryArray As [String]() = New [String](0) {"c:\test\"}

        'this loops directories
        For Each sd As [String] In myDirectoryArray
            Dim dir As New DirectoryInfo(sd)

            ' this loops file types
            For Each sFileType As [String] In myFileArray

                ' this loops files
                For Each file__1 As FileInfo In dir.GetFiles(sFileType)

                    ' add the file name to FileNames ArrayList
                    FileNames.Add(file__1.FullName)

                    ' open files for streamreader
                    Dim sr As StreamReader = File.OpenText(file__1.FullName)

                    'loop until the end
                    While sr.ReadLine() IsNot Nothing
                        LineCount += 1
                    End While
                    'close the streamreader
                    sr.Close()

                    results1.Rows.Add()
                    results1.Rows(0).Item(0) = "Filename: " & file__1.FullName
                    results1.Rows(0).Item(1) = "Count: " & LineCount

                Next
            Next
        Next

        Return LineCount



    End Function


    Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As System.Object, e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click

        Try

            DataGridView1.DataSource = GetLineCount()

        Catch ex As Exception

            MsgBox(ex.Message)

        End Try

    End Sub

    Private Sub DataGridView1_CellContentClick(sender As System.Object, e As System.Windows.Forms.DataGridViewCellEventArgs) Handles DataGridView1.CellContentClick

    End Sub

End Class
```

Comment: you need to create a datatable and iterate your results to each new row of the datatable then just bind it to the datagridview

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like this should work....

Sorry you'll need to decide where to add columns and rows as you use them in your loops or define it up front and just add data as each new row is added. Obviously don't Dim the datatable inside a loop.

```
        Dim Results1 As New DataTable

        Results1.TableName = "output"
        Results1.Columns.Add(0)
        Results1.Columns.Add(1)
        Results1.Rows.Add()
        Results1.Rows(0).Item(0) = val1
        Results1.Rows(0).Item(1) = val2

        Return Results1
```

Then just bind it to the DataGridView

```
DataGridView1.DataSource = Results1
```

Update, try something like this....

Add this at the beginning of the function....

```
Public Function GetLineCount() As DataTable 
      Results1.Columns.Add(0) 
      Results1.Columns.Add(1)
```

Then inside this loop add the other Row values...

```
For Each file__1 As FileInfo In dir.GetFiles(sFileType)

    ' add the file name to FileNames ArrayList
    FileNames.Add(file__1.FullName)

    ' open files for streamreader
    Dim sr As StreamReader = File.OpenText(file__1.FullName)

    'loop until the end
     While sr.ReadLine() IsNot Nothing
           LineCount += 1
     End While

     'close the streamreader
     sr.Close()

     Results1.Rows.Add()
     Results1.Rows(0).Item(0) = "Filename: " & file__1.FullName
     Results1.Rows(0).Item(1) = "Count: "  & LineCount 

Next
```

don't forget to change the Return value at the end of the function....

```
Return Results1
```

Comment: hello, thank you for your answer. Im trying to apply it but what would val1 and val2 be ?

Comment: val1 and val2 are your results to output to the datagridview. You could put the returned value of GetLineCount in Val1 and perhaps the file name in val2 or vice versa.  See my updated answer.

Comment: Excellent answer, thanks. I did as you told me then add datagridview1.datasource = restults1. And it does not indicate to me any mistake but however the datagrid is blank, do not load any data. Sorry to bother you but could you imagine what will be the problem?

Comment: First did you define the results set datatable, second post your updated code.

Comment: yes i did, ok i will edit the orginal question with the new code

Comment: i already added the new code on the main quiestion. If i use "datagridview1.datasource=results1" datagrid stays blank. And if i use "datagridview1.datasource=getLineCount()" it says something like not finding column 0

Comment: Try these changes....Public Function GetLineCount() As Integer to Public Function GetLineCount() As datatable and

Comment: change Return LineCount to Return Results1

Comment: You might also have to refresh or bind after this line....DataGridView1.DataSource = GetLineCount()   So DataGridView1.Refresh(), if this is post back in a web page you may also need to check for Postback condition.

Comment: You should also delete this....    Private Sub DataGridView1_CellContentClick(sender As System.Object, e As System.Windows.Forms.DataGridViewCellEventArgs) Handles DataGridView1.CellContentClick

    End Sub

Comment: great i think we r almost there. I make the changes but im getting a msgbox saying "No se pudo encontrar la columna 0 ", google translate: "could not find the column 0"

Comment: you haven't added these...  Results1.Columns.Add(0)
        Results1.Columns.Add(1)    ...  ....  ... Try and place them just after the call to start the function.

Comment: Public Function GetLineCount() As DataTable      
      Results1.Columns.Add(0)     
      Results1.Columns.Add(1)

Comment: Nice !!! it worked !!! i love you. It is showing only one result but it is working, thank you. Now i need to figure out how to make it show all the five files

Comment: Glad to hear it, not sure why you are only seeing one row, it likely has to do with your loops, but you should be able to step through the code now. Please accept the answer and post a new question if you continue to have issues.